# How to set encoding of SOAP responses in CXF client?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF to create a SOAP client. A web service response contains the following umlaut character: `[0xc3][0x9c]`, which is an `Ü`.

Of course I could manually convert this field when I read the response like:

```
String utfString = new String(isoString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
```

But I'd rather set the client to convert the ISO to UTF8 strings automatically.

Question: how can I configure this in a CXF client globally for any incoming requests?

Comment: Fix the web service - it should set the "charset=utf8" attribute correctly on the content-type.

Comment: I have no control over the webservice. If course it should, but it's not possible.

Comment: We services/soap/http is not exactly s new technology. You should report a bug and depending on your relationship with the supplier, push for a fix. And otherwise you may consider a proxy server to add the correct header so you keep the kludges out of your client code. Someone will thank you in a few years time when they do fix the we service because in most companies it's much easier to remove a rule from a proxy server than to redeploy a java application to production.

Answer (score 2):

You can set encoding as shown below.

```
@Bean
    public KPWs kpMath(SpringBus bus) {
        final JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean client = new JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean();
        client.setBus(bus);
        client.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/services/ws ?wsdl");
        client.getFeatures().add(new LoggingFeature());
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENCODING", "ISO-8859-1");
        client.setProperties(map);
        return client.create(KPWs.class);

    }
```